# Select alias property from a detached Criteria with NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I am basically trying to create this sql query in criteria. The sql query is pretty easy, but to do this with a criteria query i have to select a property from a detached criteria. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Select y0_ from 
(
    SELECT distinct TOP (1000) this_.Id as y0_, this_.InstrumentNumber as y1_ 
    FROM [SearchRecorderInstrument] this_ 
    inner join [SearchRecorderName] name1_ on this_.Id=name1_.SearchRecorderInstrument_id 
    inner join [NameType] nt4_ on name1_.NameType_id=nt4_.Id 
    inner join [SearchRecorderPropertyLegal] pl5_ on this_.Id=pl5_.SearchRecorderInstrument_id 
    inner join [DocumentType] dt2_ on this_.DocumentType_id=dt2_.Id 
    inner join [DocumentCategory] dc3_ on dt2_.DocumentCategory_id=dc3_.Id 
    WHERE name1_.FIPSCode = '26049' and name1_.LastName like 'smith%' and not (1=0) 
    ORDER BY this_.InstrumentNumber desc
) [b]
```

This is what i Have so far:

```
var criteria4 = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(SearchRecorderInstrument), "instr");

            criteria4.CreateCriteria("instr.Names", "name", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);

            criteria4.CreateCriteria("instr.DocumentType", "dt", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);

            criteria4.CreateCriteria("dt.DocumentCategory", "dc", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);

            criteria4.CreateCriteria("name.NameType", "nt", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);

            criteria4.CreateCriteria("instr.PropertyLegals", "pl", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);

            criteria4.Add(Expression.Eq("name.FIPSCode", fipsCode));

            criteria4.Add(Expression.Like("name.LastName", lastName, MatchMode.Start));

            if (partyIndicator != null && partyIndicator > 0)
            {
                criteria4.Add(Expression.Eq("name.PartyIndicator", partyIndicator));
            }

            if (firstName != null && firstName != string.Empty)
            {
                criteria4.Add(Expression.Like("name.FirstName", firstName, MatchMode.Start));
            }

            if (beginDate != null)
            {
                criteria4.Add(Expression.Ge("instr.RecordedDate", beginDate.Value));
            }

            if (endDate != null)
            {
                criteria4.Add(Expression.Lt("instr.RecordedDate", endDate.Value.AddDays(1)));
            }

            if (consFrom != null)
            {
                criteria4.Add(Expression.Ge("instr.Consideration", consFrom));
            }

            if (consTo != null)
            {
                criteria4.Add(Expression.Le("instr.Consideration", consTo));
            }

            if (documentTypeIds != null && documentTypeIds.Any())
            {
                disabledDocTypes = documentTypeIds.Where(x => !disabledDocTypes.Contains(x)).ToList();
                criteria4.Add(Expression.In("dt.Id", disabledDocTypes));
            }
            else
            {
                criteria4.Add(Expression.Not(Expression.In("dt.Id", disabledDocTypes)));
            }

            foreach (var item in legalSearchCriteria)
            {
                var val = item.Filter.FilterType.Value;
                switch (val)
                {
                    case "LIKE":
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Like("pl." + item.Filter.Field, item.Value));
                        break;
                    case ">=":
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Ge("pl." + item.Filter.Field, item.Value));
                        break;
                    case "<=":
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Le("pl." + item.Filter.Field, item.Value));
                        break;
                    case "=":
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("pl." + item.Filter.Field, item.Value));
                        break;
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in sortDescriptors)
            {
                if (item.SortDescriptorDirection.ToString() == "ASC")
                {
                    criteria4.AddOrder(Order.Asc(item.ColumnName));
                }
                else
                {
                    criteria4.AddOrder(Order.Desc(item.ColumnName));
                }
            }

            criteria4.SetProjection(
                Projections.ProjectionList()
                .Add(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("instr.Id")), "InstrumentId")
                .Add(Projections.Property("instr.InstrumentNumber"), "InstrumentNumber"));

            criteria4.SetFirstResult(skip).SetMaxResults(rowsViewed);
```

I need to select just the InstrumentId from this Detached query. And so I have come up with something like this so far, but i dont think this will work:

```
var criteria5 = sess.CreateCriteria<SearchRecorderInstrument>("instr");
            criteria5.Add(Subqueries.Select(criteria4));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you join with .CreateCriteria("ForeignCollection")
Joining with alias can be done with the extra overload .CreateCriteria("ForeignCollection", "aliasname")

In the Where part you can use "aliasname" for example "aliasname.Id" (even if this was a name in a DetachedCriteria, however your query doesn't look like it needs a detached criteria)

**Update**

I think you should consider to select only the instrument IDS in the detached criteria (i.e. criteria4) and not the instrumentnumber.
Next, you can use criteria4 for a subquery for example:

```
Subqueries.PropertyEq("instr.InstrumentId", criteria4)
```

where instr is the alias in criteria5

Use criteria5 to select the corresponding instrumentnumbers

Comment: I have edited my question a little bit, im not sure how you would use the aliasname of the detached criteria in my criteria5 query to select a property out of my criteria4 detached criteria. If you could put it in an example form that would be great. Thanks

Comment: I wish i could do that, but in order to do a distinct on the instrumentId and order by the instrument Number i have to include both properties in the select.

Comment: Ok, back to the beginning then: what is final purpose of the query? What do you want to get out of your database?

Comment: using the criteria from my criteria4 query i want to get the list of distinct InstrumentIds.